# Best design pattern to support static functions of generic classes that implements interface

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, interface

I have an interface `Operations`:

```
public interface Operations{

    Operations add(Operations op);

    Operations subtract(Operations op);
}
```

This interface should allow the user to choose how to do simple calculations. For example if the user just wants to use the data type `Integer` and its basic operations he can use the class `MyInteger`:

```
// simple implementation without type check etc..
public final class MyInteger implements Operations{
    private final int delegate;

    public MyInteger(int i){
        delegate = i;
    }

    @Override
    Operations add(Operations other){
        return new MyInteger(delegate + ((MyInteger) other).delegate);
    }
    @Override
    Operations subtract(Operations other){
        return new MyInteger(delegate - ((MyInteger) other).delegate);
    }
    (...)
}
```

In other classes there will take place calculations based on the functions of the interface `Operations`. But sometimes i need a static context like `valueOf(val)` functions that returns an implementation of the corresponding class for a given String, double, int and so on , like in this example:

```
public class Calculation<D extends Operations> {

    private final D value1, value2;
    private final D value3 = D.valueOf(4);  // cannot implement this in interface 

    public Calculation(D value1, D value2){
        this.value1 =value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public D sumPlusValue3(){
        return value1.plus(value2).plus(value3);
    }
}
```

So

```
Calculation<MyInteger> calc = new Calculation<MyInteger>(new MyInteger(1), new MyInteger(2));
Operations result = calc.sumPlusValue3();
```

In general i think i have to use a design pattern like [Builder](https://howtocodetutorial.wordpress.com/generic-builder-pattern-in-java-8/) or a [Factory](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-factory-pattern-example) to allow the user to specify which implementation he wants, like

```
Operations integerImpl = OperationsBuilder.create("Integer");
```

But also after studying those patterns, i could not find a clean way to get an implementation of the generic class `D` for `value3` in the `Calculation` class.

**EDIT 1**:

I edited the question and marked the answer from @Stefan Haustein because it was the best solution for my problem. 
But the answer from @davidxxx is also a good answer regarding my initial question - how to represent **only** a `valueOf(int val)` function.

Comment: I want to add an `int` to a `double`, is it possible? consider `Operation<OPERAND1, OPERAND2, RESULT>`

Comment: No, that should not be possible. That means it must be validated that all Operations implementations are of the same instance. In Calculations class this is satisfied because of the generic parameter, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `Calculation` you always have an instance of `D` nearby anyway, you could just make `valueOf` a non-static member of `Operations` although technically you don't need the corresponding value.

If using a "dummy" instance for `valueOf` is not an option, you could require `Class<D>` as a constructor parameter for `Calculations`. That would allow you to call `newInstance()`, perhaps providing a neutral element -- but you would still require an operation such as `addInt` to get to a concrete value. These ideas could be combined to just avoid the need of an explicit dummy value.

Another option would be to make valueOf abstract in `Calculation`, avoiding the dependency on a dummy instance, moving the burden to the Calculation instance creation:

```
Calculation<MyInteger> calc = new Calculation<MyInteger>(
    new MyInteger(1), new MyInteger(2)) {
      public MyInteger valueOf(int i) {
        return new MyInteger(i);
      }
    });

Operations result = calc.sumPlusValue3();
```

In general, this seems to be about the right balance between "purity" and "extra layers / complexity". I would lean towards being more pragmatic and avoiding overhead here -- at the expense of purity.

P.S. Another option might be to have an explicit factory interface but to store it as a field of the Operations class as a convention:

```
public final class MyInteger implements Operations{
  private final int delegate;

  public static final OperationsFactory<MyInteger> FACTORY = 
    new OperationsFactory<>() {
      @Override
      MyInteger valueOf(int i) {
        return new MyInteger(i);
      }
    };

  public MyInteger(int i){
      delegate = i;
  }

  @Override
  Operations add(Operations other){
      return new MyInteger(delegate + ((MyInteger) other).delegate);
  }
  @Override
  Operations subtract(Operations other){
    return new MyInteger(delegate - ((MyInteger) other).delegate);
  }
  (...)
}
```

This would at least keep the implementation side of everything together in one file...

Comment: If i have to use several valueOf functions like: D valueOf(String val),  D valueOf(double val) would you say it is better to have them as instance functions and put their headers to the interface with generic parameters (like in @davidxxx answer)? I don't know, but it looks a little bit dirty to have 'valueOf(val)' functions on instances that stores other values...

Comment: If there are too many, I'd split off a factory interface. Given that you only need one instance of this, you could just put it into the implementation as a static field, see added example

Comment: But in my 'Calculate' class I do not know the implementation of 'D', so i do not know which FACTORY i should use? For example there exists an other implementation of 'Operations': 'MyDouble' than I do not know if I should call 'MyDouble.FACTORY.valueOf(..)' or MyInteger.FACTORY.valueOf(..)

Comment: The factory would need to be an additional constructor parameter for Calculation

Answer (score 2):

1) Initial problem : factory invocation

Here :

```
private final D value3 = D.valueOf(4);  // cannot implement this in interface
```

You want value `value3` with a generic that is not a factory.
Defining `valueOf()` in the interface (so as an instance method) is not either a solution.

As alternative, you could introduce a factory parameter in the `Calculation` constructor to have a way to value `value3`.

So replace :

```
private final D value3 = D.valueOf(4);

public Calculation(D value1, D value2){
    this.value1 =value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
}
```

by :

```
private final D value3; 

public Calculation(D value1, D value2, FactoryD factoryD){
    this.value1 =value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
    this.value3 = factoryD.create(4);
}
```

or better use the `Function` functional interface for the factory :

```
private final D value3; 

public Calculation(D value1, D value2, IntFunction<D> factoryD){
    this.value1 =value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
    this.value3 = factoryD.apply(4);
}
```

You could so use it like that :

```
Calculation<MyInteger> calc = new Calculation<>(new MyInteger(1), new MyInteger(2), MyInteger::new );
Operations result = calc.sumPlusValue3();
```

But `Operations` misses something.

2) No way to represent `Operations` value.

Actually, `Operations` defines operations methods but no way to display the object value  :

```
public interface Operations{

    Operations add(Operations op);

    Operations subtract(Operations op);
}
```

You should rather define with a way to get the value and make the interface generic to handle any type of value :

```
public interface Operations<T> {

    Operations<T> add(Operations<T> op);

    Operations<T> subtract(Operations<T> op);

    T getValue();

}
```

`MyInteger` can so be defined as :

```
public final class MyInteger implements Operations<Integer> {

    private final int delegate;

    public MyInteger(int i) {
      delegate = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Operations<Integer> add(Operations<Integer> other) {
      return new MyInteger(delegate + other.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Operations<Integer> subtract(Operations<Integer> other) {
      return new MyInteger(delegate - other.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
      return delegate;
    }
}
```

And `Calculation` could be so defined with two generics : one for the `Operations` and another for `Operations` return type :

```
public class Calculation<C, D extends Operations<C>> {

    private final D value1, value2;
    private final D value3; 

    public Calculation(D value1, D value2, IntFunction<D> factoryD){
        this.value1 =value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.value3 = factoryD.apply(4);
    }

    public Operations<C> sumPlusValue3(){
        return value1.add(value2).add(value3);
    }        
}
```

You can so use this code in this way :

```
Calculation<Integer, MyInteger> calc = new Calculation<>(new MyInteger(1), new MyInteger(2), MyInteger::new );
Operations<Integer> result = calc.sumPlusValue3();
System.out.println(result.getValue());
```

Output :

> 7

Comment: Thanks for the return type hint. I also like the approach to work with a generic Function/IntFunction. The disadvantage for me is that i have an additional parameter and that i could need some other trasformations, for example D valueOf(String val), D valueOf(Int val), ... Would you say an instance function would be more suitable in this case?

Comment: You are welcome. I proposed `IntFunction` as you hardcoded numeric value in `Calculation` to create a D instance: `this.value3 = factoryD.apply(4);` If you want to be able to pass any type to build a D instance, you could specify the `Function<C, D>` function. Of course, in the  `Calculation` class, you should refer to the `C` type and not numeric or `String` value as in the `Function` the `C` type is generic and not a specific type.